# Нарезать sprite sheet с даными из xml файла

Tags: c++, png, спрайт

есть .xml файл с содержимым анимации:

```
<sequence name="run_s.xml" source="./run_S*.png">
<img regx="56" regy="90" name="run_s" w="0" h="0" />
<framelist>
    <frame regx="20" regy="62" x="76" y="0" w="34" h="68" name="run_S001.png" />
    <frame regx="20" regy="61" x="0" y="141" w="34" h="69" name="run_S002.png" />
    <frame regx="20" regy="61" x="38" y="69" w="35" h="65" name="run_S003.png" />
    <frame regx="20" regy="61" x="181" y="69" w="35" h="62" name="run_S004.png" />
    <frame regx="20" regy="61" x="145" y="132" w="36" h="59" name="run_S005.png" />
    <frame regx="19" regy="61" x="145" y="69" w="35" h="62" name="run_S006.png" />
    <frame regx="19" regy="62" x="147" y="0" w="36" h="66" name="run_S007.png" />
    <frame regx="19" regy="62" x="38" y="0" w="37" h="68" name="run_S008.png" />
    <frame regx="19" regy="62" x="0" y="71" w="37" h="69" name="run_S009.png" />
    <frame regx="19" regy="62" x="0" y="0" w="37" h="70" name="run_S010.png" />
    <frame regx="19" regy="62" x="111" y="0" w="35" h="67" name="run_S011.png" />
    <frame regx="20" regy="62" x="184" y="0" w="36" h="65" name="run_S012.png" />
    <frame regx="20" regy="62" x="109" y="69" w="35" h="62" name="run_S013.png" />
    <frame regx="20" regy="63" x="109" y="132" w="35" h="61" name="run_S014.png" />
    <frame regx="20" regy="63" x="74" y="69" w="34" h="63" name="run_S015.png" />
    <frame regx="20" regy="63" x="38" y="135" w="34" h="65" name="run_S016.png" />
```

подскажите как можно быстро нарезать спрайты, чтоб размер был 120х120, но без потери центра ?